# What do I need to do if my Google upload key is expired?

Tags: google-play, google-play-console

In my upload keystore file which I sign my apps with before I upload it to the store I found the following:

```
Valid from: Thu Dec 19 14:23:38 CET 2019 until: Mon May 06 15:23:38 CEST 2047
```

So this means my key isn't valid after 2047. I found a lot of things about what to do when I [lose or compromise](https://support.google.com/googleplay/android-developer/answer/113476?hl=en&ref_topic=7072031) my upload key. But I couldn't find anything about when my upload key expires. What am I supposed to do in this situation?

Comment: There has been no guidance from google about how to handle when keys expire, they said at a previous Google I/O that they going to come up with something but did not say when

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**Update:** The upload key can now be reset directly in the Play Console. No need to contact Play Developer support.

---

The upload key can be reset at any time by reaching out to the Play Developer support. It is usually done when the key is lost or compromised, but nothing prevents you from resetting it for a different purpose like the key about to expire.

There is little documentation about the expiration case because it's so far away that who knows what signing will look like in 20+ years.

Comment: I'm glad to know it isn't my lack of research but the lack of the information Google gave about this.